# Search for any three characters inside quotes "..." and replace with same three characters inside quotes plus a blank space

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to search for all occurances of ANY three characters enclosed in double quotes, such as "CTF" or "2FS", and replace them with "CTF " and "2FS ".

This seems like a simple problem and I feel like there should be a simple solution.  What the hell is going on??

```
Find what: "..."

Replace with: \1
```

I have tried all of these as well:

```
Replace with: "\1 " 

Replace with: "\1\s"

Replace with: "... "
```

EDIT:
I have updated my search code to use Toto's suggestion:

```
Find what: "[^"]{3}\K"
```

But, when I use:

```
Replace with: _" (where _ is a blank space)
```

Nothing changes in the "found" string

The results I am hoping for is to have:

```
"CTS" --> "CTS "
"A&D" --> "A&D "
"2PW" --> "2PW "
etc.
```

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Also, if the strings are fixed just look for `"CTF"` and replace with `"CTF" `. Same with `"FFS"`. Or is there something else you need to do and you didn't include in your question?

Comment: There are over 2000 lines of code, with different characters inside the quotes.  So yes, I could search for those two specific examples, but there are other characters combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^"]{3}\K"`
- Replace with: `"`    #a space and a double quote
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           # a double quote
[^"]{3}     # 3 characters other than double quote
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
"           # a double quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
 "          # a space and a double quote
```

**Capture screen (before):**

[image]

**Capture screen (after):**

[image]

Comment: The find what: code correctly finds all instances of any three characters within quotes,  but the replace does not seem to be working.  I do have wrap around and Regular Expression selected

Comment: Still struggling with the REPLACE WITH portion, which does not seem to be working atm

Comment: @GBL:Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55518286/edit) and add sample text and expected result. I've run this regex on a sample file of mine and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions.  I have updated my original question to include my expected results.  When I select replace using your code, the original found value such as "DSL" does not change, where as I was hoping it would change to "DSL ".

Comment: @GBL: I've added capture screen. It works for me. Do you click on "Replace **All**"

Comment: @GBL: I didn't ask you to add my answer in your question but add **real** sample input file and expected result

Comment: Thank you again, for your help.  I was NOT selecting Replace All, rather only Replace.  When I selected Replace All instead, it did work.